# How can I create a faceted search like Redfin.com using ElasticSearch?

Tags: google-maps, geospatial, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a search very similar to Redfin.com using ElasticSearch. There is a geo distance facet but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. Here is an example of Redfins search which has a feature similar to "map clusters":

http://www.redfin.com/homes-for-sale#!disp_mode=M&lat=33.488012063731574&long=-117.406087074585&market=socal&v=8&zoomLevel=9

Important notes:

1. The data returned is not simply a list of map markers that are clustered with the Google Maps Map Clusters system. I tried this and it was far too much data. The data returned is already summarized
2. The location points move dynamically so it seems the geo distance facet w/multiple locations is not being used either.

Thanks,
DK

Comment: You could facet on bigger cities ... just with the normal termfacet ... and include one specific facet only if the city is in the bounds of your current query (store this either purely in-memory on the client site or pre-fetch this in another query or try to use all city and if speed+memory is not bad go with this)

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch does not yet have a "geo cluster facet". If you are interested, follow https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1689.

I don't know if Redfin is doing the clustering on the fly, or has predefined regions for different zoom levels. If latter, you can use a simple term facet to get the number of hits for each region.